# Editing text directly from the command line

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have a text column for keeping some markdown.

I'd rather not build a web interface to edit entries with this column.

Is there a way to launch a text editor from the command line to edit in place?

Or perhaps is there a way to easily dump a plain text file into this column for a particular row?

Would be nice to be able to fire up VIM and edit some basic text without the overhead of building an interface (that doesn't feel needed?)

Comment: What command line?  I didn't think rails had a command line.

Comment: I detect elitism. Nothing was mentioned about Rails. My question is a fair one. Bash shell command line, or any shell really.

Comment: I'm so elite that I read your tag.  Which is 'rails-postgresql'.

Answer (score 0):

Running `\e` should launch your default text editor.

Comment: Could you give an example of selecting a row and editing a particular column for that row in a text editor?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this sample Perl code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Slurp;
use File::Temp;
require DBI;
$|=1;

my $dbh=DBI->connect('dbi:Pg:'); $dbh->{RaiseError}=1;

my ($val)=$dbh->selectrow_array('select foo from bar where id=?', undef, $ARGV[0])
  or die "No row for $ARGV[0]";
my ($fh, $filename) = File::Temp::tempfile();
binmode $fh;
print $fh $val;
close $fh or die $!;
system "vi $filename" and die $?;
$val=read_file($filename);

$dbh->do('update bar set foo = $2 where id=$1',undef,$ARGV[0],$val)
   or die "Row not updated";
```